# Adding content to div with javascript - 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get this error from the code below:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('grid');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '   <figure>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg01.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </figcaption>
</figure>');
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47wwrbc1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line breaks in the string are causing the issue. To fix this you could put the string on a single line:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('grid');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<figure><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg01.jpg" alt=""><figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</figcaption></figure>');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/sqqLhLpm/)

Or alternatively you can concatenate it on different lines:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('grid');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<figure>' +
    '<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/123941/placeimg01.jpg" alt="">' +
    '<figcaption>' +
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua' +
    '</figcaption>' +
'</figure>');
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/47wwrbc1/2/)

Comment: Or ES6 template strings, or joining an array, or escaping newlines with backslashes.

Comment: @gcampbell yep, there's hundreds of methods. These are the quickest and easiest though.